# Issue with Scipy's Optimize Curve Fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

As a start, I'm not the most experienced at programming (or that great either). I sort of just google functions and guess until it works. As such, a lot of the talk on Stack Exchange and Documentation goes way, WAY over my head.

I'm having an issue with Scipy's optimized curve fitting function. I'm attempting to fit a Gaussian to some voltage data I got. I run the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = np.genfromtxt("C:/Hydrogen Data/peak1.csv", delimiter = ',', skip_header=1)
position = data[:,1]
voltage = -data[:,2]

plt.plot(position, voltage)
plt.show()

def gaussian(x, *p):
    A, mu, sigma = p
    return A*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))

fit, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian, position, voltage, p0 = [0.2, 100, 2])
plt.plot(fit)
plt.show()
print(pcov)
```

and am getting an error that the elements of the covariance matrix cannot be evaluated. More specifically, I'm getting this out: "OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated (category=OptimizeWarning)." I'm not fully sure what I can do to approach it, as some of the forum posts I've read about it went way over my head. Does anyone have any tips?

Here's the data I'm fitting to and its graph

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19PGpqb5pBxCqspCyMOJPF-brI-hvjfbN/view?usp=sharing
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1MKY.png

Thank You!

Comment: Hi Nathan. Welcome! I want to gently let you know that there's some rude members of the community that will respond quite negatively to "I sort of just google functions and guess until it works." Having said that, I wish you the best of luck. I understand where you're coming from.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact output? Are you getting an SVD convergence error? A linalg error?

Comment: Okay just edited it. It does print the matrix, so the program doesn't stop on the optimize function. All of the matrix elements are just infinity though...

Answer (score 1):

The best fit gaussian to any curve can be found analytically.

```py
A = np.sum(voltage);
mu = np.sum(position * voltage) / A;
sigma = np.sqrt(np.sum((position - mu)**2 * voltage));
```

But your data does not fit well to a gaussian, because a gaussian vanishes far from the center.
[image]

Furthermore it is skewed, even if we translate the gaussian the fit is not very good.

```py
plt.plot(position, voltage)
v0 = min(voltage)
A = np.sum(voltage - v0);
mu = np.sum(position * (voltage - v0)) / A;
sigma = np.sqrt(np.sum((position - mu)**2 * (voltage - v0))/ A);
plt.plot(position, v0 + A / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) / sigma * np.exp(-(position - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)))
plt.ylim(0, None)
```

[image]

You can probably find better models to describe this curve than the Gaussian. The Normal distribution naturally appears in stocastic systems.